# Client persistent socket

Tags: netty

Can someone point tome what needs to be done to reuse the socket connection created by the client in netty? If I create a channel on client side in netty, can multiple concurrent threads use the same channel without synchronization? What is the correct way to handle this scenario in netty 3.2?

-TK

Answer (score 1):

Yes the same Channel can be used by different Threads as all methods are thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

There are no issue with calling channel.write() from different Threads.
The read is done by handling events in a custom Handler so there are no multi-threading issue. It is your business to decide what to do when a messageReceived event is fired.

The basic way to get the Channel is to use the ClientBootStrap and do that:

```
ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(factory);


        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new ChannelPipelineFactory() {

            public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
                ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
                pipeline.addLast("LOGGER", new LoggingHandler("CLIENT", true));
                return pipeline;
            }
        });

        // Connect to the server, wait for the connection and get back the channel
        ChannelFuture connectFuture = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));

        // Wait until the connection attempt succeeds or fails.
        Channel channel = connectFuture.awaitUninterruptibly().getChannel();
```

Another way could be to implement a handler like this and add the handler to the Pipeline in the factory. Then you can access the Channel any time but the first solution seems the best way to do the trick!

```
  public class PublicChannelHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {

        Channel channel;

        public Channel getChannel(){
            if (channel == null) {
                 throw new IllegalStateException("No underlying Channel is associated with this handler at the moment.");
            }
            return this.channel;
        }

        @Override
        public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
            this.channel=ctx.getChannel());
        }
    }
```